# New session ID generated for each request

Tags: java, google-kubernetes-engine

**Problem summary:**

New session ID is generated for each request in my application, but only within Google Cloud Container Engine infrastructure.

**Root cause:**

I found the root cause of the problem. The session affinity set for Ingress does not work as I expected. Here is how it's created:

1. I'm creating deployment with 2 replicas (basic java application with servlets)
2. I'm creating NodePort service as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) (but using YAML)
3. I'm creating Ingress controler using YAML
4. I'm adding a cookie based session affinity to Ingress via Google Cloud Console

And here is what I get when I'm refreshing the page in a browser (POD name is added inside "[]"):

```
[app-deployment-428779295-3xq7f] Session created: node01peqkxiewv08i1hkh0zonc8fmw0
[app-deployment-428779295-lp1r2] Session created: node017hf0svs0n6u816virgk4qkxk40
[app-deployment-428779295-3xq7f] Session created: node030t1v2oamg3p1x3tw55m2tdno1
[app-deployment-428779295-3xq7f] Session exists: node030t1v2oamg3p1x3tw55m2tdno1
[app-deployment-428779295-lp1r2] Session created: node0drzofij3ljx1tgn2z3dcj12y1
[app-deployment-428779295-lp1r2] Session exists: node0drzofij3ljx1tgn2z3dcj12y1
[app-deployment-428779295-lp1r2] Session exists: node0drzofij3ljx1tgn2z3dcj12y1
[app-deployment-428779295-3xq7f] Session created: node01wlgfm248y7f3fagzuu3thga82
[app-deployment-428779295-lp1r2] Session created: node0qiqpch5b1u4g1lvbphkj3djqh2
[app-deployment-428779295-lp1r2] Session exists: node0qiqpch5b1u4g1lvbphkj3djqh2
[app-deployment-428779295-lp1r2] Session exists: node0qiqpch5b1u4g1lvbphkj3djqh2
[app-deployment-428779295-3xq7f] Session created: node01gfdfatrj0premffkwywc5ori3
```

The question is - how to fix it?

**Original problem description:**

- Spring MVC application (tested also on simple servlet with the same results, so this is not the case)
- Running on jetty 9.4.6 docker image (default configuration; happens also on tomcat 8.5.15 docker image)
- Application deployed as ROOT.war
- Application is deployed on 2 nodes (2 PODs) with Ingress load balacing, HTTPS and cookie-based session affinity.
- Setting explicite cookie domain and path does not help.
- Other cookies managed by application are working just fine

The problem does not occur when I run it from jetty-maven-plugin or from docker image locally.

Have anybody else encounter such an issue?

Comment: How do you identify your users? If it's per source IP, then that might be the case. Container Engine has a bit of complicated networking, so you should not rely on source IP address on the request. Use cookies to identify users and sessions.

Comment: Hi, please see my edited post. I've created a simple webapp that behaves the same (no users, just session). Jetty (tomcat also) uses cookies by default to manage sessions. I can see the cookies in the browser, and also the cookie is being send with each request. But for unknown reason it is ignored and the serwer creates new session.

Comment: Hmm, I've just reconfigured deployment and when there is only single POD, the sessions works fine. So I found the cause. Now, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem at the moment by leaving only 1 replica and set `sessionAffinity: None` (which is default), but this is not helpful for scalable applications.

The first solution I was thinking was to make a Redis pod and configure it in my spring application as the session holder, then I leave the `sessionAffinity: None` because I'm not holding the security context in my pod memory, instead I'm leaving it in my Redis database and because of this it doesn't matter which spring application pod will process the request because it can identify the session by interrogating the Redis database. By doing this, you are not going to be limited by the deployment infrastructure. You can check out [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html) guide.

The second solution is to configure a sessionless aplication by using a OAuth2 implementation with an authorization server and configure your spring application as the client, but this is already a more complicated solution and requires more work.

Comment: I've considered Redis myslef but finally I'm doing it the other way. I've switched to nginx ingress controller, which is not perfect yet but does the job (handles session affinity "cookie")..