# How to create session-aware LoadBalancer via Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

I have read all the documentation that I've found on the [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer), [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress) and [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress) and I still cannot find the information on how to create Ingress resource that will work with sticky session. Yes there are some examples like [this one](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/affinity/cookie/nginx) but it does not guide me through the whole process. I'm not sure if I should create NodePort before using this configuration or not. I've described my current problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554241/new-session-id-generated-for-each-request) and it seems to be similar to the one described [here](http://nishadikirielle.blogspot.com/2016/03/load-balancing-kubernetes-services-and.html), but still, I was unable to find a clear answer/tutorial on how should I do it properly. What is the best practice here? There should be one, as this seem to be a problem that many web applications could have.

Answer (score 2):

This is less a question about Kubernetes and more a question about what kind of load balancer you have decided to use. [Here](https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/) is the Nginx documentation on how to implement session persistence.

If you were to use the Kubernetes Nginx ingress controller, the ingress definition is pretty simple. If you look at the source code for [nginx.tmpl](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/nginx/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl#L245), you will see that the capability already exists. [This](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/examples/affinity/cookie/nginx/sticky-ingress.yaml) yaml is probably all you would need.

[Here](https://crondev.com/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/) is an example of how an nginx ingress controller can be set up. It even has examples of ingress rules, you could probably just add the above yaml to it. You'll notice that the nginx controller does use NodePort to expose its IP address.

Comment: Hi, this is 100% question about kubernetes and GKE. I do not want to know how to balance my request using nginx itself. I thought the whole idea around the kubernetes was to abstract and standardize such things as much as possible. As for documentation, I know it is there, but it's shredded and currently there is no way to implement load balancing with sticky session properly without trying a couple of solutions and finding the proper one by myself. Ideally, the best solution would be just to add single entry in ingress.yaml and have sticky session just working, but I know it's not there yet.